# Question appearing twice in Google search results

Tags: bug, questions, google, seo

I was doing a Google search and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733455/inserting-a-new-text-at-given-cursor-position) twice in a row in the Google search.

Although, the to links are a little different. They are:

- [Inserting a new text at given cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733455/inserting-a-new-text-at-given-cursor-position)
- [Inserting a new text at given cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733455/inserting-a-new-text-at-given-cursor-position/33258611) (note that this one has `/33258611` at the end)

[This](https://www.google.com/search?q=codemirror+insert+text+without+moving+cursor) is the Google search, and here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how to prevent it?

Comment: I think the `/33258611` denotes an answer that has been deleted.  The page with the extra `/33258611` is including the `/33258611` in its `<link rel=canonical`, in any case, so Google isn't going to merge them.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: There are no deleted answers on the linked question.

Comment: It's the post id of one of the answers on the page. Why Google shows it I'm not sure.

Comment: Another example, searching on google.be for `knockout component dynamic` shows `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33653137/load-knockout-components-dynamically` and `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33653137/load-knockout-components-dynamically/33655427` right next to each other, with the extra number being the post ID of the answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The result with `/33258611` after it is part of the [comment link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733455/inserting-a-new-text-at-given-cursor-position/33258611#comment37101278_23736834) for this comment

> Does this work properly in IE9? I am using it IE9 but once the text is inserted, I am not able to add any chars further. Is this something u noticed it when you developing the code mirror? – Chetan Jun 5 '14 at 13:29

but the google link lacks the fragment part: `#comment37101278_23736834` which is the reason it doesn't get highlighted.

As both urls are unique Google assumes it presents results from two different pages to you.

The id '33258611' belongs to another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33258611/578411) on that same question which can be quickly learned from [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/453142/show-all-comments-and-post-ids-for-a-question?question=23733455). Maybe the comment was moved between answers but it needs someone with mod powers to confirm.

Comment: It seems weird that Google would do this, though, given that the page has a `<link rel="canonical">` tag. But the fault seems to lie with Google

Comment: @Pekka웃 The extra `/33258611` is in the `<link rel="canonical">`, which (I think) represents to Google that the pages are indeed different.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom indeed!

Comment: Seems that this has now been fixed (no such duplicate result on the linked Google search).

Comment: @cybermonkey, well that isn't true. I just now searched the same link given in the question, and I got the same thing.

Comment: Weird, perhaps it depends on region?

Comment: Not fixed. Searching for `knockout component dynamic` on google.be results in a similar situation.

Comment: After almost two years, still not fixed. I imagine the SO team is not in a rush to fix getting twice the weight in Google, but from a user's POV this is quite annoying.

Comment: @Tgr you can report abuse at [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93713?hl=en). That should teach those slackers....

Comment: @Tgr Now there are no canonical tags at all anymore, anywhere on SE. Things get worse...