# Shortlinks are not marked up to point to the canonical page?

Tags: bug, google, seo

Using Google Search on "systemd timer unit runs if expired during suspend?" returns two top results.

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351829/systemd-timer-that-expired-while-suspended
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/351967

For some reason, Google is not detecting that #2 is actually a redirect to #1.  (HTTP 302).

I think we can assume that Google knows what a HTTP redirect is...

```
HTTP/2 302
date: Sat, 17 Feb 2018 11:23:49 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
location: /questions/351829/systemd-timer-that-expired-while-suspended/351967#351967
...
```

But ah! There's an extra `/351967` on the end of the redirect target. Can we get rid of that?

The above answers the "why" question "[Question appearing twice in Google search results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319386/question-appearing-twice-in-google-search-results)". My question is whether Stack Overflow is going to fix it :).

It sounds like stuff can be moved around and that's why you need the extra ID; fair enough. However, could it not be fixed by adjusting the `<link rel="canonical">` that Google reads?

Comment: That "why" question is marked as resolved, and in fact this question is pretty much the answer to it.  My question here is if SO is going to fix their bug :).

Comment: No, they are not going to fix that as it will break the answer navigation.

Comment: That sounds like an answer to a question; an answer that is not explained on the "duplicate" :-P.  I don't really understand, but it sounds like stuff can be moved around and that's why you need the extra ID, ok.  However why can it not be fudged to fix the `<link rel="canonical">` that Google reads?

Comment: cross-site discussion on rel canonical: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130749/improper-use-of-rel-canonical-is-hurting-search

Answer (score 2):

> Could it not be fixed by adjusting the `<link rel="canonical">` that Google reads?

Consider [Improper use of rel=canonical is hurting search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130749/improper-use-of-rel-canonical-is-hurting-search) as pointed out by @rene.

Your first URL is a link to the question.  Your second URL is a link to the answer.

If there is more than one page of answers, it is undesirable to canonicalize all answers to the first page, which will not include the text of all answers.